# MySQL for Pycharm

Tags: mysql, sql, pycharm

I'm creating a web application on pycharm using flask framework. i have to create database. i dont have any sql database in system and have no idea how it should be done.  i want to know how it can done?
  should i download MySQL first and then create db files in pycharm?
  please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion,if you have install MySQL database,you follow this,open pycharm and click File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter,then select your Python interpreter and click install button (the little green plus sign),input "MySQL-Python" and click the button "install package",you will install MySQL-Python successfully.If you have not install MySQL database,you need install MySQL database first.

Or you may go with.

From Windows Command Prompt / Linux Shell

install using wheel

pip install wheel
Download 32 or 64 Bit version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

64-Bit

pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
32-Bit

pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
Using Anaconda2:

Open a Command Prompt

$ conda install mysql-python
Press y to proceed with installation